# How to declare a lambda's operator() as noreturn?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, attributes, noreturn

How can the `operator()` of a lambda be declared as `noreturn` ?

Ideone accepts the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>  
int main() {
    []() [[noreturn]] { std::exit(1); }();
    return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.5 rejects it with:

```
error: 'noreturn' attribute cannot be applied to types
```

You can try it in godbolt: http://goo.gl/vsuCsF

Which one is right?

**Update**: the relevant standard sections appear to be 5.1.2.5, 7.6.3, 7.6.4 but after reading does it still isn't 100% clear to me (i) what is the right behavior, (ii) how to mark the operator() of a lambda as `noreturn`.

Comment: To your question (ii), use `__attribute__((noreturn))` in G++. It works for years. There is [a regression](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89640) in GCC 9, though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Clang is correct. An attribute can appertain to a function being declared, or to its type; the two are different. `[[noreturn]]` must appertain to the function itself.  The difference can be seen in

```
// [[noreturn]] appertains to the entity that's being declared
void f [[noreturn]] ();    // §8.3 [dcl.meaning]/p1:
                           // The optional attribute-specifier-seq following a
                           // declarator-id appertains to the entity that is declared."
[[noreturn]] void h ();    // §7 [dcl.dcl]/p2:
                           // "The attribute-specifier-seq in a simple-declaration 
                           // appertains to each of the entities declared by
                           // the declarators of the init-declarator-list."

// ill-formed - [[noreturn]] appertains to the type (§8.3.5 [dcl.fct]/p1: 
// "The optional attribute-specifier-seq appertains to the function type.")
void g () [[noreturn]] {}
```

Indeed if you compile this in g++ it tells you that

```
warning: attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
 void g () [[noreturn]] {}
                      ^
note: an attribute that appertains to a type-specifier is ignored
```

Note that it doesn't emit a warning that `g()` actually does return.

Since an "*attribute-specifier-seq* in the *lambda-declarator* appertains to the type of the corresponding function call operator or operator template" (§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda]/p5) rather than to that operator/operator template itself, you can't use `[[noreturn]]` there. More generally, the language provides no way for you to apply an attribute to the `operator ()` of a lambda itself.

Comment: that is, there is no way to use attributes on the operator() of a lambda?

Comment: @gnzlbg No, there's no way.

Comment: @T.C. Is there any reason for that, or hasn't the committee thought about it. Has there been any proposals for solving this issue?

Comment: @user877329, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2173r0.pdf

Answer (score 4):

So a lambda delcarator has the following grammar the draft C++ standard section `5.1.2` *Lambda expressions*:

```
( parameter-declaration-clause ) mutableopt exception-specificationopt attribute-specifier-seqopt trailing-return-typeopt
```

and the noreturn attribute is indeed a valid *attribute-specifier-seq* so from a grammar perspective I don't see a restriction from section `7.6.3` *Noreturn attribute* it says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> [...]The attribute may be applied to the declarator-id in a function
>   declaration.[...]

which does not seem to forbid your use but it does suggest that it is not allowed. If we look at section `7.6.4` *Carries dependency attribute* it says:

> [...]The attribute may be applied to the declarator-id of a
>   parameter-declaration in a function declaration **or lambda**[...]

the fact that it explicitly includes the lamda case strongly indicates that section `7.6.3` is meant to exclude lambdas and therefore `clang` would be correct. As a side note Visual Studio also rejects this code.

Comment: From C++11 5.1.2.5: "An attribute-specifier-seq in a lambda-declarator appertains to the type of the corresponding function call operator". That is, the [[noreturn]] attribute on the lambda applies to the type of the operator(). No need to specifically add in 7.6.3 that it also applies to a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

> `[C++11: 7.6.3/1]:` The *attribute-token* `noreturn` specifies that a function does not return. It shall appear at most once in each *attribute-list* and no *attribute-argument-clause* shall be present. **The attribute may be applied to the *declarator-id* in a function declaration.** The first declaration of a function shall specify the `noreturn` attribute if any declaration of that function specifies the `noreturn` attribute. If a function is declared with the `noreturn` attribute in one translation unit and the same function is declared without the `noreturn` attribute in another translation unit, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

I concede that this wording, as is, doesn't prohibit the attribute from appearing elsewhere, but in concert with seeing no evidence anywhere in the standard for it, I don't think this is intended to work with lambda declarations.

**Therefore, Clang would be correct.**

It may or may not be telling that [there was a patch proposal to Clang to allow GCC-style `noreturn` attributes on lambdas](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140310/101215.html), but *not* the standard form.

Unfortunately, this feature is not included in [GCC's list of extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html#C_002b_002b-Extensions), so I can't really see exactly what's going on here.

Comment: From C++11 5.1.2.5: "An attribute-specifier-seq in a lambda-declarator appertains to the type of the corresponding function call operator". That is, gcc is right I think.

Comment: I understand it as an attribute in a lambda appertains to the corresponding operator(), so noreturn should apply to operator(), and not to the type of the lambda.

Comment: @gnzlbg: Hmm okay I see what you mean but the above-quoted clause says that `noreturn` is applied to declarations (kinda), not types?  Clang at least clearly thinks that applying it to types is wrong. I don't think it's very clear.

Comment: Me neither, I've read it 10 times and am still not sure about it. The terminology is very specific and I do not master it.

Answer (score 1):

Reading this in 2022, and the following appears to be working for me.
*Hopefully it helps anyone stumbling on this post.*

```
#include <cstdlib>  
int main() {
    []() __attribute__((__noreturn__)) { std::exit(1); }();
    return 0;
}
```

Another version creating a macro:

```
#define NO_RETURN __attribute__((__noreturn__))

#include <cstdlib>  
int main() {
    []() NO_RETURN { std::exit(1); }();
    return 0;
}
```