# How to add an attribute to a lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda, attributes, noreturn

Suppose I have a lambda

```
auto func = [](std::string msg) { throw std::runtime_error(msg); };
```

(admittedly, this example makes little sense, but that's not the point). If this were not a lambda, but an ordinary function, I would declare it with the `noreturn` attribute as in

```
[[noreturn]] void func(std::string msg) { throw std::runtime_error(msg); }
```

Can this also be done for a lambda? (I tried several variations with clang 3.5, but without any success.)

---

*edit* Using `Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`, I tried

```
auto func = [](std::string msg) -> [[noreturn]] void { throw std::runtime_error(msg); };
```

or

```
auto func = [](std::string msg) [[noreturn]] { throw std::runtime_error(msg); };
```

but both were rejected. Is this an incompleteness/bug of clang 3.5?

Comment: See [How to declare a lambda's operator() as noreturn?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26888805/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Indeed. I missed that before asking. Marked my own question as dupe now ...

Answer (score 0):

The following works in g++ 4.9.3:

```
void foo()
{
  auto func = [] (std::string msg) [[noreturn]] { throw std::runtime_error(msg); };
}
```

Works at http://ideone.com/49Ietf too.

Comment: So from the answer to the dupe, it appears that gcc 4.9.3 was accepting ill-formed code ...

Comment: @Walter, That appears to be the case. I wonder if there was any deliberation in the standards committee to explicitly prohibit use of `[[noreturn]]` for lambda functions.

Comment: I think the fact that one cannot attribute a lambda with `[[noreturn]]` was/is no intention of the standard, but its unfortunate consequence. *The language provides no way for you to apply an attribute to the `operator()` of a lambda itself.* Alternatively, one may accept the above code as language extension.